# Implicit conversions for members that are types

Tags: scala, implicit, dependent-type, path-dependent-type, scala-2.11

given:

```
implicit class WithRetType[T, U](x: T => U) {
  type Ret = U
}
```

this:

```
val foo = (_: Int) * 2
val x: foo.Ret = 3
```

yields:

```
  error: type Ret is not a member of Int => Int
val x: foo.Ret = ???
          ^
```

the following however works:

```
val foo = (_: Int) * 2
val fooR = new WithRetType(foo)
val x: fooR.Ret = 3
```

Don't implicit conversions kick in for access of members that are types?

Comment: This seems to be the relevant source code: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala but it takes time to plough through it :)

Comment: my guess is that this facility does not work on type declaration level.

Comment: I tried looking at the reference, but no where I could find this restriction. Looks to me a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversions cannot be used to access type members. Irrespective of the implementation details, this can be seen as a logical consequence of two items in the spec:

- The *path* that leads to a path-dependent type must have only *stable* elements ([Paths](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#paths) in the spec)
- An implicit conversion is a method/function, whose result is always *unstable*

The two are therefore incompatible: you cannot have an implicit conversion on the path leading to a path-dependent type, because the conversion itself is unstable, making the path invalid.